# Apple App Store certificates from clients

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I'm still struggeling with Apple App-Store Certification for iOS Apps.

Now I have a client who has his own developer account, but I'm developing for him and doing all the stuff. I have a separate developer Account on my own. The Client authorized my account on Itunes Connect, as App Manager.
He created a Distribution Certificate, an App Id and a Provisioning Profile for the App ID and sent the certificate and the Profile to me. I included it in the keychain and can now select those in XCode.
But XCODE says: the provisioning Profile "doesn't include any certificate for which the private key is installed in keychain."

What am I missing? Do I need the private key of the clients? Or is there an other way to do this?

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried Xcode ---> Preferences ---> Account -----> Download Manual Profiles (Select the right team above , before you download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Ask your client to export developer certificate from keychain(.p12) and share it with you.

2) You have to create a new developer certificates(By removing old one from keychain) by upload a new CSR certificate so the private key will be installed in your system.

if  issue is with both(Developer and Distribution)certificate you need both to be exported from your client machine.

Comment: Ah thanks, I was thinking something like that. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You need both certificate and private key (.p12). Ask your client to export the private key and shared it with you. Once you got the private key, install it in your system and you are good to go. Follow this tutorial to export the private key.

https://www.ironpaper.com/webintel/articles/how-to-share-an-ios-distribution-certificate/

Make sure your client export the private key of distribution certificate.